# How can I nest these commands in i3-msg

Tags: linux, shell, i3

When i3wm is started, I want to start a terminal which watches ongoing processing. I know how to do all this separately, but I am having troubles to combine it.

The commands in vacuum are:

```
urxvt -hold -e sh -c <command>
watch -n 5 <command>
ps ax | grep -E 'ssh|rsync'
```

I currently have the following in `~/.config/i3/config`:

```
exec --no-startup-id i3-msg "workspace 10; exec urxvt -hold -e sh -c 'watch -n 5 \"ps ax | grep -E \'ssh|rsync\'\"'"
```

This doesn't really work. I am having troubles to combine all these commands.

Can this be done without creating separate shell scripts for each step?

Answer (score 0):

There is probably some way to do this with many levels of nested single quotes, but there is also a simpler solution. You can easily decrease number of levels of nested quotes using `watch -x`.

Try this:

```
exec --no-startup-id i3-msg "workspace 10; exec urxvt -hold -e watch -n 10 -x sh -c \"ps ax | grep -E 'ssh|rsync'\""
```